# Webpack dev server proxy not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, http-proxy-middleware

I am trying to set webpack dev server proxy. However, I am getting following error:

```
500 - Error occurred while trying to proxy to: localhost:8080/abc/v1/user/search/?id=123122
```

Here is my webpack devserver config:

```
    proxy:  {
        "^/abc/v1/**":  "https://my-services.net/",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false
    }
```

I get following error in VS Code IDE:

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request (UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE)
```

As mentioned in various posts, I have tried following solutions but none seems to help:

```
'process.env': {
    'NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED': '0'
}

strict-ssl=false
```

I am using webpack-dev-server version **2.11.2**.